# F-distribution in R

Tags: r

I tried to calculate the mean and variance of two random variables X~F(m=2,n=5) and Y~F(m=10,n=5) from their density functions(df). It would be straightforward since R has df function already, however,

```
> X~F <- df(1,m=2,n=5)
[1] 0.3080008  
> Y~F <- df(1,m=10,n=5) 
[1] 0.4954798
```

Numerically, mean should equal to (n-2)/n, and var should be 2n^2(m+n-2)/(m(n-2)^2(n-4) which do not match the result.

It will be super painful to integrate the whole pdf since it involves with beta distribution. Any suggestions guys?

Comment: `df` gives the density distribution. Not clear why what you calculated should match the mean and the variance.

Comment: @nicola i got confused thought this asks me to use density functions but looks like it would be a rf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have formulas for the mean and variances so why not compute the mean and variance that way?

What you are doing is finding the P(X = 1) given that X ~ F(m=2,n=5) when you run F <- df(1,m=2,n=5) in R.

You can randomly drawing values from the F distribution and then use the mean() and var() function, but these answers won't be exact.

```
rf(n, df1, df2, ncp)
```

so you would fill in

```
rand_values<-rf(100000,2,5)
mean(rand_values)
var(rand_values)
```

and you should get something close to the exact values.

Comment: `df` isn't `P(X<1)` (that would be `pf`), it's the probability *density* at 1.

Comment: thanks guys. i got confused thought this asks me to use density functions but looks like it would be a rf